# Values of words

Tags: letters

If:

> SCORE = 7
>   NUMBER = 10
>   ZEBRA = 16
>   QUESTION = 17
>   RAINBOW = 12
>   AXOLOTL = 14

Then:

> ANSWER = ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ANSWER = 9

Because

> You convert the letters into Scrabble letter values and sum them all up 
>  
>  SCORE $\rightarrow 1+3+1+1+1 = 7$ 
>  NUMBER $\rightarrow 1+1+3+3+1+1 = 10$ 
>  ZEBRA $\rightarrow 10+1+3+1+1 = 16$ 
>  QUESTION $\rightarrow 10+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 = 17$ 
>  RAINBOW $\rightarrow 1+1+1+1+3+1+4 = 12$ 
>  AXOLOTL $\rightarrow 1+8+1+1+1+1+1 = 14$ 
>  
>  So ANSWER $\rightarrow 1+1+1+4+1+1 = 9$

Comment: Nice answer!! :D

Comment: Well done! Scrabble is one of my favourite games.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> 16

I arrived at this by

> Assume the word value is based on the sum of arbitrary values of the vowels

then

> o+e=7, u+e=10, e+a=16 (and this would also be the value of ANSWER), u+e+i+o=17, a+i+o=12

which gives

> u+i=10, a-u=6, a+i=16 and finally, o= -4.

finishing gives

> o = -4, e = 11, u = -1, a = 5, i = 11 which fits all the word values and gives the value of ANSWER as 16

Comment: Good try, but incorrect

Comment: @RohitJose this looks like a valid answer based on the clues given...if this is incorrect, could you perhaps provide another word whose value wold disprove this?

Comment: Okay, I'll add another one